# How to stop SimpleMessageListenerContainer instances?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, message-listener

We have several hosts which sends out messages through an Exchange. For these several hosts, i have created an instance of SimpleMessageListenerContainer that binds to a queue and host. I have registered a listener for the container. On Message retrieval, i look for a certain kind of message. If i receive the message, i would like to stop the container but i dont know how to do it on the MessageListener end since i dont have the container instance there. Can someone please help me? Sorry if i have confused anyone.  I am very new to AMQP and trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the container with an @Resource annotation and then call stop() on it when you receive the desired message.

Comment: Please, be more specific. It is one more question, not an answer

Comment: Each instance of container is associated with a connection factory. How do i know which instance to inject?

Comment: If you want to stop a specific host that received a specific message, you'll need something in the message to identify which host received it.  As far as I know, there's no way to trace a message back to the container that picked it up, using plain JMS or otherwise.  

The only option that I can think of is to use AOP to intercept the message when the container is about to hand it off and inject the reference.